# PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to look for DB values and use properties file as fallback

Tags: java, spring

I'm wondering if its possible to use the value in DB before properties file in PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer. So what I want to achieve is to load the properties file, and if any keys exist in the database, use that. Right now I don't know where to start, but I'm assuming that there is a method/class that I can override or interface that I need to implement.

Just mention the method/class/interface and I will gladly start from there. TIA

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer has a "properties" property that can point to an object that retrieves the database values. See an example here: http://pure-essence.net/2011/02/10/spring-loading-properties-from-database-with-a-twist/

Also, you'll want to set "ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" to true on the bean that config that loads the properties from the database. That way you can add another PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer as a fallback to provide properties that are not found in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to merge properties, you may want to implement [InitializingBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html) on your target bean. Your hook will be the afterPropertiesSet method, where you can go about with your kung-fu.

BTW, Spring loads and overrides beans definitions in the order the container encounters it.

Comment: I would prefer ninja moves :) but thanks, I will try this option.