# why when i run project it can not read properties from properties file?

Tags: java, spring, mule

I have service.properties and service-properties.xml in mule based project. How can i define that service.properties should load before service-properties.xml.
Because i am using the properties of service.properties in service-properties.xml.
because i have this code in service-properties.xml file:

```
    <context:property-placeholder
        location="classpath:mule/service.properties"
        properties-ref="propertiesHolder" />
    <context:annotation-config />   
   <spring:bean id="propertiesHolder"
        class="MyClass">
        <spring:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </spring:bean>
    <spring:bean id="dataSource"        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

       <spring:property name="driverClassName value="${db.driverClassName}" />
        <spring:property name="url" value="${db.url}" />
        <spring:property name="username" value="${db.username}" />
        <spring:property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
    </spring:bean>
```

My project is build successfully but when i run project it can not resolve db.driverClassName, db.url, ... and db.password from service.properties but i have them in service.properties file.

Comment: Adding a snaphot of directory structure will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could read properties from file and from database by this configuration:

```
   <spring:bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <spring:property name="locations">
            <spring:value>classpath:mule/service.properties</spring:value>
        </spring:property>
        <spring:property name="properties">
            <spring:value>propertiesFromDataSource</spring:value>
        </spring:property>
    </spring:bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading the properties files and config files within the same context using context:property-placeholder then Mule/Spring will take of that for you and there shoould be no problems:

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/configuring-properties

Comment: my project is build. when i run my project i have db.url=${property.url}  in my an my xml file. the value of property.url is in the my .properties file. but it can not read property.url from service.properties because i think it is not loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I think your application is failing to resolve the properties because you included **both** a `location` attribute and a `properties-ref` attribute in your `property-placeholder` configuration.  The `properties-ref` attribute is intended to replace the `location` attribute, in order to provide the values of the properties from a `java.util.Properties` object.

Try this:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:mule/conversion/service.properties" />
```

You can then simply refer to the properties in your `dataSource` bean.

The reason there is no explicit reference connecting the bean using the properties (dataSource) and the bean that loads the properties is that the `<context:property-placeholder />` element defines a [BeanFactoryPostProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanFactoryPostProcessor.html).  This is a special kind of bean that can modify the definition of other beans before they are instantiated.  It searches for bean properties using the `${propertyName}` syntax and replaces them before Spring tries to instantiate them.

**UPDATED: How to load properties from database, configured by properties**

If your goal is to load your configuration properties from a database, and to configure the connection to that database with another properties file, check out [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26384626/spring-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-load-from-db).

Comment: @Rayan Hoegg I need to read properties from properties file and also i need to read properties which is saved in database. when i seperate them in 2 property plase holder also i have the same problem